# Cocos2d Layer not displayed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I believe I have my head round the scene and layer concept and understand that a scene can include several layers. I have created a simple project
`HelloWorldLayer` containing a menu to other scenes, a `GameScene` and `InputLayer`.

The InputLayer will include a StickyButton and Jotstick, and this layer will be added as a child to the game scene, using the following:

GameScene.m

```
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
GameScene *layer = [GameScene node];
[scene addChild: layer z:0

InputLayer *inputLayer = [InputLayer node];
[scene addChild: inputLayer z:1];
```

I can’t get the content of the layer to display.

Doing some random tests I found that if I use the `inputLayer` in `HelloWorldLayer` than it work, if I navigate to a new scene no display?

Am I missing anything obvious.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you pushed the scene into the shared director?

Comment: @Ramy Al Zuhouri I am a nood to this so not sure, I can get it to work from the initial scene but only fails if a navigate to another. Initailly I thought it was an issue with the layer order but from the tutorial etc it appears OK.

Comment: How do you navigate to the other scene?